# Rails client side validations: how to show positive messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, client-side-validation

In the initializer of `client_side_validations` gem I can change `field_error_proc` to show error messages inline. But how can I show positive messages? For example, while user fills out password field I would show: **"too short"**, **"not bad"**, **"secure"** and add a green checkbox after user leaves the field.

**EDIT:** the password was just an example, not the best, what I really need it just to have 2 states valid/invalid for a field in the form, that the user filled out. The `client_side_validations` gem displays error messages if something goes wrong, if it's ok it displays nothing - and I'd like to show user that he's done it right.

Comment: Any specific reason why you would want to do this using Rails? Since the password length and strength display functionality can be achieved using jQuery itself (i.e., without tying up with rails). Loads of plugins out there. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/password_strength The reason to take this route would be two fold: 1. You don't need Database access or http request both of which are required when authenticating a user 2. Loads of plugins already available out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to use the gem but the [Callbacks](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Callbacks) should provide a way to achieve the functionality you deserve.

`clientSideValidations.callbacks.element.pass(element, callback, eventData)` may be used to do additional processing if the form element has passed the validation.